# Storyboard in style Color Animation using a dynamically changeable Color

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am changing the style of my buttons using a `<Style />` defined in a `<ResourceDictionary />`. The goal is to have all of the colors used in this entire resource dictionary to come from a `Settings` file which I already got working. But now I am at a loss on what to do with my `Button` styling since it has a storyboard color animation. The two colors it is currently fading back and forth to work fine, naturally, when defined. But trying to get them out of my Settings file and use them as colors for my storyboard has been so far fruitless.

**< Edit** : The setting that is used has been manually set to System.Windows.Media.Color. Not the default System.Drawing.Color. **Edit >**

Here is the XAML code that I use:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Settings" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Settings}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonMain" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.ButtonMain}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonFade" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.ButtonFade}"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMain}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushTextForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="outer" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonFade}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="Hand" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Border x:Name="inner" Margin="-2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="inner" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="ButtonBlink">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                            Duration="0:0:1"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            AutoReverse="True">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="<!--This would be ButtonMain-->" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="<!--This would be ButtonFade-->" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ButtonBlink" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ButtonBlink"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind via `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="{Binding Color,
                                         Source={StaticResource ButtonMain}}"
                         KeyTime="0:0:0" />
     <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="{Binding Color,
                                          Source={StaticResource ButtonFade}}" 
                          KeyTime="0:0:1" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
```

**UPDATE**

Above posted code works in case you define Style inline but won't work if Style is declared under Resource section because Binding in Storyboard won't allow it to freeze and can't be reused.

However, `StaticResource` is allowed. So, as a workaround instead of animating `Color`, you need to animate `Brush` so that static brushes can be used in Storyboard.

```
<Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                  AutoReverse="True">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                               Value="{StaticResource ButtonMain}"/>
   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1"
                                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                  AutoReverse="True">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                               Value="{StaticResource ButtonFade}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: This gives the usual
`"Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads."` exception, sadly : /

Comment: Oh yes. I tried it in inline style where it works perfectly but not in case defined under resource section. :/

Comment: Produces the same exception for me :(